# Safari nested flexbox performance issue

Tags: performance, layout, flexbox, safari

I have a complex flex-based angular page, with a big amount of nested flex items. I need to have customizable stretch elements to the end of page and use scroll by some of inner containers.

Chrome/Edge/Firefox doing well, as expected. But Safari start to freeze whole page.

I have analyzed styles of all elements. And, for demonstrate this issue, I created demo page.

```js
let startTime = new Date().getTime();

window.onload = () => {
  window.onload = null;
  setTimeout(() => {
    const endTime = new Date().getTime();
    const timeSpend = endTime - startTime;
    const loadTime = `Loading time: ${timeSpend}ms`;
    console.log(loadTime);
    const input = document.querySelector("label");
    input.innerText = loadTime;
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.05);
}

.block-item {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

label {
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label></label>
<div class="flex-item"><span>0</span>
  <div class="block-item"><span>1</span> <!-- block here -->
    <div class="flex-item"><span>2</span>
      <div class="flex-item"><span>3</span>
        <div class="flex-item"><span>4</span>
          <div class="flex-item"><span>5</span>
            <div class="flex-item"><span>6</span>
              <div class="flex-item"><span>7</span>
                <div class="flex-item"><span>8</span>
                  <div class="flex-item"><span>9</span>
                    <div class="flex-item"><span>0</span>
                      <div class="flex-item"><span>1</span>
                        <div class="flex-item"><span>2</span>
                          <div class="flex-item"><span>3</span>
                            <div class="flex-item"><span>4</span>
                              <div class="flex-item"><span>5</span>
                                <div class="flex-item"><span>6</span>
                                  <div class="flex-item"><span>7</span>
                                    <div class="flex-item"><span>8</span>
                                      <div class="flex-item"><span>9</span>
                                        <div class="flex-item"><span>0</span>
                                          <div class="flex-item"><span>1</span>

                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or demo on codepen: https://codepen.io/JBeen/full/LYBwYmJ

Tried on Safari 16.3 and Safari TP 16.4 on Macbook Pro 16 M2 Max
Loading time: ~3.5s

When I increase amount of nested elements and add 1 element -- loading time increase twice, and became ~7s. So after adding several more nested elements -- page start to freeze completely.

Does Safari have an issue on official bug tracker?
Or what I'm doing wrong?